# Simple function to return shift in 7 weekdays

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am working on a computer program that, when given a date, returns the date of the nearest Sunday.  Currently, the weekdays are numbered Sunday=1, Monday=2, Tuesday=3, etc.
How can I find the function f(x) = y for

- f(1) = 0
- f(2) = -1
- f(3) = -2
- f(4) = -3
- f(5) = 3
- f(6) = 2
- f(7) = 1

Comment: I'm not even sure how to tag this question.  Is this calculus?  Let me know if I should post this question somewhere else.

Comment: What kind of function are you looking for?  `IF( x<5, 1, 8 ) - x ` would work if you have an Excel-like IF function which could be replaced by a suitable indicator or step function

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a pure mathematical function, perhaps including modulus? that does not use an IF statement.

Comment: @Henry, your Excel-like formula is exactly what I was looking for.  @ HenningMakholm was just the first to express it mathematically below.

Comment: If `x` is an integer, then you can simply use `1-x+7*(x/5)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have your function, nicely tabulated in your question! If you want to express it a little more compactly, you could write
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1-x &\text{when } x \le 4 \\ 8-x & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

There's nothing wrong or non-mathematical about expressing a function by cases when that is the clearest and simplest thing to do!

Comment: @Henry: Yes, fixed.

Comment: You're probably right.  But the purist in me wants a pure mathematical solution without resorting to IF conditional, if possible.

Comment: @Baodad: This IS a pure mathematical solution. There's nothing non-mathematical about a conditional definition. There are various tortured ways of disguising the condition so it doesn't look like a condition, but it would be at the cost of clarity -- and defining a function in an unclear way, _that_ is not the way of good mathematics.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, in terms of mathematics, you are quite right.  Since my application is in computer processing, some part of me feels like the conditional evaluation slows things down (albeit surely not in any noticeable way).  I'll give it a bit longer just to see, then I'll accept your answer.  Cheers!

Comment: @Baodad: I would still write `(x<=4?1:8)-x` and trust the compiler to implement that in an efficient way. If you really want to avoid the conditional, `((11-x)%7)-3` should work too, but I am by no means convinced that a remainder operation is more efficient than the conditional -- since the compiler probably doesn't know the range of $x$ it would need to engage division circuitry at run time, and _that_ is usually not fast.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, *you are the man*, except it is ((11-x))%7)-3 in my case.

Comment: @Baodad: Right, somehow I failed to add 7 to 4 correctly in my head :-)

Comment: And if you _really_ want to squeeze the last cycles out of it at the cost of readability, try `(((4-x)>>3)&7)-(x-1)`, or `((4-x)>>>29)-(x-1)` if you're in something like Java and have a guaranteed 32-bit-logical-right-shift operator handy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another option:

$$f(x)=(1-x)\cdot\Big(1-\Big\lfloor\frac{x}{5}\Big\rfloor\Big)+(8-x)\cdot\Big\lfloor\frac{x}{5}\Big\rfloor$$

---

Or if you want to simply this:

$$f(x)=1-x+7\cdot\Big\lfloor\frac{x}{5}\Big\rfloor$$

Comment: Nice and simple, if we're only dealing with integers!  And no need for modulo!

Answer (score 0):

[Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%281%2C0%29%2C%282%2C-1%29%2C%283%2C-2%29%2C%284%2C-3%29%2C%285%2C3%29%2C%286%2C2%29%2C%287%2C1%29%7D%20fit%20polynomial) is your friend.
$$f(x)=106-\frac{15061 x}{60}+\frac{15883 x^2}{72}-\frac{2261 x^3}{24}+\frac{749 x^4}{36}-\frac{91 x^5}{40}+\frac{7 x^6}{72}$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Wolframalpha.  But there has *got* to be a simpler function that this.  I'm only dealing with integers 1 to 7, -3 to +3 in the result.

Comment: @Baodad The function you defined was already fine. I like the look of a continuous fit best. **EDIT** My function doesn't use an *if* statement by the way.